# li with class="active" always shown on mouseleave

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, mouseleave

I have setup a fiddle for you to watch:

http://jsfiddle.net/xq50ebt3/

I have a navigation-menu which contains some li's that dynamically get the class="active" when the user is watching a document inside it's parental folder.

On "hover" on the li's the other containing ul's/submenu's shall get shown by this script, which works fine:

```
   $('.navigation li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').slideDown()
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul').slideUp()
    }).find('ul').hide()
```

As there is always a li-element which class="active" on pageload, I want this to be shown when the page is loaded; i've done this by using this code:

```
$('.navigation li.active').find('ul').slideDown();
```

My problem now is: on mouseleave of the navigation-div the last shown and slided-down ul gets slided up...which is fine...but **I want the ul which contains the li with class="active" to be shown on mouseleave.**

Any hint will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it by using this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7prdd1th/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navigation li").hover(function(){
        $(".navigation li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    $(".navigation").mouseleave(function(){
        //alert('123');
        $(".navigation li").removeClass("active");
        $('.navigation ul li ul li.aktiv').parents('li').addClass('active');
    });       
});
```